# how to search inside the array of objects in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have this kind of structure in mongoDB
my schema

```
{
 user: String,
 skills: Array
}
```

for every user How to search all users by a particular skill

Answer (score 1):

You can use the $in operator

```
db.collection.find({ skills: { $in: ['programming', 'cooking'] }})
```

or Mongoose models.

```
Model.find({ skills: { $in: ['programming', 'cooking'] }})
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/